# How can i grant System Admin like permission to a user to Accept/Reject records

Tags: approval-process

I need to create a custom setting like "Admin for Approval" and need to assign this setting to a users.

Now every user that owns this custom setting will behave like Admin user for approval process like he can `Reassign|Approve/Reject` any record as any System Admin can do.

So now record can be `Approve/Reject` by the actual Approver or by the user that own "Admin for Approval" custom setting.

I don't want to write all new custom logic to achieve this. Is there any straight forward way to achieve this?

Can i use standard "ProcessSteps" related list to achive this if yes then how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The only global permissions I know of that will allow you to control the approval process are the "Modify All..." permissions.

Assuming granting those permissions aren't an option and depending on the object, one potential solution would be to create a Queue with the Users you want to be able to control your processes. You could then assign the approvers of your processes to the Queue as well as any additional users.

Answer (score 1):

Modify all permission on respective object on profile will serve the purpose.

I had quite similar requirement and achieved using this step.

Regards,
Jagan